# Muestre las posibles combinaciones de "n" números y calcular su promedio

Tags: python, python-3.x, algoritmos, matemáticas

Programa que reciba `"n"` números, muestre sus posibles combinaciones, realice el promedio de dichas combinaciones. Intenté con conjunto potencia

```
def conj_pot(cp):
    lista = [[]]
    for x in cp:
        n_sub_conj = [sub_conj + [x] for sub_conj in lista]
        lista.extend(n_sub_conj)
    return lista
```

### Respuesta esperada

```
ejemplo = conj_pot([4,5,6])

print(ejemplo)
[[],[4],[5],[4,5],[6],[4,6],[5,6],[4,5,6]]
```

### ¿Cómo obtener el promedio de cada sub lista? Es decir:

```
[4] promedio = 4/1 = 4

[5] promedio = 5/1 = 5

[4,5] promedio = (4+5)/2 = 4.5

[6] promedio = 6/1 = 6

[4,6] promedio = (4+6)/2 = 5

[5,6] promedio = (5+6)/2 = 5.5

[4,5,6] promedio = (4+5+6)/3 = 5
```

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de combinaciones buscas? ¿Con o sin repetición, permutaciones, ...? Indícanos, modificando la pregunta, el resultado que esperas para esos tres números que has puesto en el ejemplo, así como los promedios y todo cuanto quieras calcular... Ah, y échale un vistazo a este enlace, es importante: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Consideraciones

***Nota: La respuesta está al final de este post***

La pregunta ofrece un ejemplo con `[4, 5, 6]` pero voy a trabajar con estos números inicialmente `[9, 11, 8, 5]`.

El motivo de esta decisión es para usar los esquemas de:

> [Como obtener promedios de una matriz triangular sin emplear condicionales](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/245934/como-obtener-promedios-de-una-matriz-triangular-sin-emplear-condicionales)

Asimismo quiero acotar, que si bien su planteamiento y solución fueron para **R**, en dicho post, se describió el algoritmo, lo cual ayuda en la respuesta que se va plasmar acá, incluyendo los matices que tiene **Python** y dando otro enfoque a la pregunta, sin descuidar claro su respuesta al final.

## Indexando

En este caso se puede visualizar `[9, 11, 8, 5]` como la diagonal de una matriz cuadrada cuyas dimensiones son exactamente iguales a la longitud de la diagonal principal, en este caso cuatro (`4`):

[image: matrizTirangulaInferior]

Nótese además que la matriz triangular inferior contiene todas las combinaciones que se requieren con sus respectivos promedios, porque da lo mismo `(9+11)/2` que `(11+9)/2`.

> Antes de continuar es oportuno indicar que el indice para las filas es `i` y para las columnas es `j` y que `longitud` es el `largo de la diagonal`.

Al observarse la estructura de la matriz (`4x4`) se aprecia que no hay operaciones de `promedio` en la última columna, eso implica que el indice `j` va de `0` a `longitud` *(en realidad sería a `longitud-1` pero se necesita también los valores de la diagonal)*.

Por otra parte, las filas sí tienen operaciones en la última de ellas, es decir: `i=longitud`.

Asimismo es importante ver que `i>j` esto sumado al hecho que los saltos en las filas de una matriz son discrecionales y como en este caso son `de uno a uno`, se puede afirmar que `i=j+1`.

Lo anterior se puede verificar de la siguiente manera:

Cuando `j=0`, el indice `i` comienza en la fila `1` y cuando `j=longitud`, se tiene `i=longitud+1` *(en realidad sería a `longitud` pero se necesita también los valores de la diagonal)*.

## Python

Visto lo anterior se requiere dos (02) funciones:

- Una función de ayuda del tipo anónima que promedie listas y que sea capaz de evitar la [forma indeterminada](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forma_indeterminata) `0/0` y el `infinito = n/0` para todo `n` diferente de cero (`0`), esto porque en la respuesta se ve que uno de los subconjuntos es una lista vacia.
- La función que calcule los promedios de la matriz triangular y que devuelva su diagonal con las demás combinaciones.

> #### La función anónima para promediar listas

Esta tendría la siguiente forma

```
meanList = lambda l: sum(l)/(len(l) or 1)
```

Aquí lo importante es cuando: `l=[]` su longitud será `cero` y la suma de sus elementos también. Pero si se prueba lo siguiente:

```
### (len(l) or 1)  ###
print(0 or 1) # Python imprime 1 (Interes en este caso)
print(3 or 1) # Python imprime 3 (Interes en este caso)
print(0 or 2) # Python imprime 2

print(0 and 1) # Python imprime 0
print(0 and 2) # Python imprime 0
print(0 and 0) # Python imprime 0

print(3 and 0) # Python imprime 0
print(3 and 1) # Python imprime 1
print(3 and 2) # Python imprime 2
```

Lo anterior implica que se evita poner condicionales `if` para que se value el denominador si es o no cero (`0`).

Si bien en este caso no va ser necesario emplear esta característica como se verá más adelante, me pareció oportuno generalizar la función anónima, para salvar la forma indeterminada, porque sí se usará en la función `conj_pot(cp)` publicada en la pregunta.

> #### La función para combinar y promediar la matriz triangular

Si bien se menciona una matriz, todo el trabajo es a través de su diagonal, en tal sentido, no es necesaria la construcción de una matriz, **sólo se le emplea como marco de referencia para comprender como se indexa la diagonal**.

```
def combinaPromMatrizTriangular(diagonal):
  ld = len(diagonal) # Longitud de la diagonal como vector
  vectorComb=[[]]    # Aqui iran las combinaciones con sublistas
  vectorProm=[0]     # Aqui iran los promedio de las combinaciones
                     # La funcion anonima meanList no evaluara
                     # en este caso la forma indeterminada 0/0

  for j in range(0,ld):                         # Columnas
    for i in range(j+1,ld+1):                   # Filas
      sc=diagonal[j:i]                          # Sub conjunto de la diagonal
      vectorComb.append(sc)                     # Se agrega subconjunto
      vectorProm.append(meanList(sc))           # Se promedia subconjunto

  # se retorna conjunto con sus promedios
  return [vectorComb, vectorProm]
```

> #### Comprobación

Para los datos alcanzados `[4,5,6]` en la pregunta se tiene lo siguiente:

```
a = combinaPromMatrizTriangular([4,5,6])
print(a[0])   #Combinaciones
# [[], [4], [4, 5], [4, 5, 6], [5], [5, 6], [6]]

print(a[1])  #Promedios
# [0, 4.0, 4.5, 5.0, 5.0, 5.5, 6.0]
```

Aunque me parece estupenda la forma de hacer listas con **Python** `[i*i for i in x]` en este caso como hay dos operaciones -combinar y sacar promedio- que deben hacerse en los bucles anidados `for` no vi oportuno hacerlo de esa manera.

Para terminar, quisiera acotar que la lista de combinaciones completa `a[0]` puede ser ordenada también si se requiere.

No obstante, considero que dado lo extenso de la pregunta y al ser **el orden de listas dentro de una lista viable con diferentes enfoques**, se efectué esta en una nueva pregunta si se considera necesario.

## Rpta.: Promedio Listas dentro de una lista

Como ya se tiene la función anónima generalizada `meanList` se construye una función `promedioListas(x)` que la llame:

```
meanList = lambda l: sum(l)/(len(l) or 1)

def promedioListas(x): return [meanList(dL) for dL in x]
```

Y dado que la función `conj_pot(cp)` arroja los subconjuntos incluyendo el vacio no se tendrá incovenientes como ya se explicó

```
print(promedioListas(conj_pot([4,5,6])))
# [0.0, 4.0, 5.0, 4.5, 6.0, 5.0, 5.5, 5.0]
```