# Crear función que permita encontrar el porcentaje de incremento o decrecimiento, pero con unas restricciones

Tags: r, funciones, porcentaje

Tengo una base de datos de la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Deseo crear una función que me permita determinar el porcentaje de variación, por ejemplo
porcentaje entre 564 y 4568, después 564 y 213, después 564 y 564.

Después 4568 y 213,
4568 y 564. Después 213 y 564.

Lo mismo para cada código, intenté algo de esta forma, pero me toma el valor anterior

```
porcentaje <- function(x) {
  round((x/lag(x) -  1)*100)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La idea sería, dado un vector, a cada elemento `2:n` calcular el porcentaje a partir del elemento `1:n-1`. Efectivamente terminará siendo una matriz triangular de `n x n-1`. Podemos armar una función:

```
porcentajes <- function(col) {
  len <- length(col)  
  sapply(1:(len-1), function(x) c(rep(NA, x), ((col[(x+1):len]/col[x]) - 1)*100))
}
```

Pero, yo le agregaría algunas mejoras **(1)** contemplar el caso de un vector de longitud menor a 1 y **(2)** Configurar nombres de filas y columnas para hacer las matrices más claras:

```
porcentajes <- function(col) {
  len <- length(col)
  if (len <= 1) return(NA)
  m <- sapply(1:(len-1), function(x) c(rep(NA, x), (col[(x+1):len]/col[x] - 1)*100))
  rownames(m) <- col
  colnames(m) <- col[1:(len-1)]
  m
}
```

Con esta función, que retorna una matriz, podemos aplicarla a cada grupo de valores de `Codigo` así:

```
lapply(split(df$PXN, df$Codigo), porcentajes)

$`321-2`
            678      1558     2314
678          NA        NA       NA
1558   129.7935        NA       NA
2314   241.2979  48.52375       NA
12353 1721.9764 692.87548 433.8375

$`369-8`
          1524       978      234
1524        NA        NA       NA
978  -35.82677        NA       NA
234  -84.64567 -76.07362       NA
2347  54.00262 139.97955 902.9915

$`455-1`
           564      4568      213
564         NA        NA       NA
4568 709.92908        NA       NA
213  -62.23404 -95.33713       NA
564    0.00000 -87.65324 164.7887
```

Esto debería funcionar de forma independiente de la cantidad de filas de cada grupo, pero sería importante asegurarse que los grupos esten ordenados `df <- df[order(df$Codigo),]`

Comment: Excelente, ejemplo que permite identificar los codigos

Answer (score 1):

### Sobre la pregunta

Al ver la estructura del resultado final, se está hablando de una matriz triangular inferior.

Aquí se detalla cómo se implementó con más detalle en R lo anterior

[Como obtener promedios de una matriz triangular sin emplear condicionales](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/245934/como-obtener-promedios-de-una-matriz-triangular-sin-emplear-condicionales)

La única diferencia sería calcular la expresión: `( x / x_previo - 1 ) * 100`, proporcionada en la pregunta, en lugar del promedio.

### Datos

```
df <- read.table(text="
Codigo PXN
455-1 564
455-1 4568
455-1 213
455-1 564
321-2 678
321-2 1558
321-2 2314
321-2 12353
369-8 1524
369-8 978
369-8 234
369-8 2347
", header = TRUE)
```

Si bien los códigos se repiten igual cantidad de veces (4 por cada tipo) se está considerando el caso en que no lo sean.

Adicional a lo anterior hay que capturar los elementos PXN (estos serán las diagonales de las matrices triangulares inferiores) para cada código a través de un bucle `for`

```
codigos <- unique(as.vector(df$Codigo))
print(codigos)
# "455-1" "321-2" "369-8"
```

### Matriz Triangular

Refactorizando el código del [post](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/245934/como-obtener-promedios-de-una-matriz-triangular-sin-emplear-condicionales) que se mencionó más arriba

```
ratiosTriangularInferior <- function(diagonal, codigo){
    len <- length(diagonal)
    m <- matrix(0, nrow=len, ncol = len)
    porcentaje <- c()
    label <- c()

    for (j in 1:(len-1)) {        # columnas
        for (i in (j+1):len){     # filas
            print(paste0('(',diagonal[j],'/',diagonal[i],'-1)*100'))
            m[i,j] <- diagonal[j]/diagonal[i] - 1
            label <- c(label,paste0(diagonal[j],'-',diagonal[i]))
            porcentaje<-c(porcentaje,m[i,j]*100)
        }
    }

    print(round(m, digits = 2))

    porcentaje <- round(porcentaje, digits = 2)
    mm <- matrix(c(rep(codigo,times=length(label)),label,porcentaje),ncol=3)

    mm
}
```

Los `prints` que contienen se pueden omitir pero permiten visualizar el paso a paso:

```
# [1] "455-1"
# [1] "(564/4568-1)*100"
# [1] "(564/213-1)*100"
# [1] "(564/564-1)*100"
# [1] "(4568/213-1)*100"
# [1] "(4568/564-1)*100"
# [1] "(213/564-1)*100"
#       [,1]  [,2]  [,3] [,4]
# [1,]  0.00  0.00  0.00    0
# [2,] -0.88  0.00  0.00    0
# [3,]  1.65 20.45  0.00    0
# [4,]  0.00  7.10 -0.62    0

# [1] "321-2"
# [1] "(678/1558-1)*100"
# [1] "(678/2314-1)*100"
# [1] "(678/12353-1)*100"
# [1] "(1558/2314-1)*100"
# [1] "(1558/12353-1)*100"
# [1] "(2314/12353-1)*100"
#       [,1]  [,2]  [,3] [,4]
# [1,]  0.00  0.00  0.00    0
# [2,] -0.56  0.00  0.00    0
# [3,] -0.71 -0.33  0.00    0
# [4,] -0.95 -0.87 -0.81    0

# [1] "369-8"
# [1] "(1524/978-1)*100"
# [1] "(1524/234-1)*100"
# [1] "(1524/2347-1)*100"
# [1] "(978/234-1)*100"
# [1] "(978/2347-1)*100"
# [1] "(234/2347-1)*100"
#       [,1]  [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]  0.00  0.00  0.0    0
# [2,]  0.56  0.00  0.0    0
# [3,]  5.51  3.18  0.0    0
# [4,] -0.35 -0.58 -0.9    0
```

Pero cómo el OP no indica la estructura que desea asumo que debe ser un `dataframe` por tanto la respuesta final se dará en este formato

### Bucle For

Se llama la función `ratiosTriangularInferior` (3 veces en este caso) para obtener las combinaciones de los porcentaje por cada tipo de código

```
names <- c("Codigo","Ratio-PXN","Porcentaje")
ans <- matrix(names, ncol=3) # aca se almacenan los resultados parciales

for (i in 1:length(codigos)){
  diag <- df[df$Codigo==codigos[i],]$PXN
  print(codigos[i])
  ans <- rbind(ans, ratiosTriangularInferior(diag, codigos[i]))
  cat("\n")
}
```

Se le da la estructura al dataframe

```
ans <- as.data.frame(ans)
ans <- ans[-1, ] 
colnames(ans) <- names
rownames(ans) <- NULL
print(ans)

#    Codigo  Ratio-PXN Porcentaje
# 1   455-1   564-4568     -87.65
# 2   455-1    564-213     164.79
# 3   455-1    564-564          0
# 4   455-1   4568-213     2044.6
# 5   455-1   4568-564     709.93
# 6   455-1    213-564     -62.23
# 7   321-2   678-1558     -56.48
# 8   321-2   678-2314      -70.7
# 9   321-2  678-12353     -94.51
# 10  321-2  1558-2314     -32.67
# 11  321-2 1558-12353     -87.39
# 12  321-2 2314-12353     -81.27
# 13  369-8   1524-978      55.83
# 14  369-8   1524-234     551.28
# 15  369-8  1524-2347     -35.07
# 16  369-8    978-234     317.95
# 17  369-8   978-2347     -58.33
# 18  369-8   234-2347     -90.03
```

Comment: Justo lo que estaba buscando