# Obtener posibles combinaciones-conjunto potencia de un data frame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Tengo el siguiente data frame:

```
         FECHA  CODIGO ORIGEN  TENOR USADO
0   07/05/2020  MV0001      N    5.0     x
1   08/05/2020  MV0002      C    5.0     0
2   09/05/2020  MV0003      E    3.0     x
3   10/05/2020  MV0004      I    4.0     0
4   11/05/2020  MV0005      N    8.0     0
5   12/05/2020  MV0006      N    2.0     x
6   13/05/2020  MV0007      C    4.5     0
```

Del anterior data frame quiero hallar las posibles combinaciones de la columna `'TENOR'`, y que sólo se impriman los valores cuyo promedio esté entre 4.0 y 5.0, siempre y cuando el valor de la fila adyacente en la columna `'USADO'` sea 0.

**Finalmente espero algo como:**

**1.** un filtro respecto a los valores de `'USADO'` igual a 0

```
        FECHA  CODIGO ORIGEN  TENOR USADO
1  08/05/2020  MV0002      C      5     0
3  10/05/2020  MV0004      I      4     0
4  11/05/2020  MV0005      N      8     0
```

**2.** Las posibles combinaciones de los valores de la columna `'TENOR'`, los promedios de estas combinaciones y que solamente se impriman los promedios mayores a 4.0 y menores a 5.0.

**2.1.** Que me muestre cuál es el `'CODIGO'` de cada uno de los valores usados, es decir, si la condición la cumplen los códigos `'MV0002'` y `'MV0004'` me deberá mostrar su valor promedio:

```
['MV0002','MV0004'] == 4.5
```

**Lo que he intentado:**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

tenorEntrada = 4.5
toneladas = 200
numPilas = toneladas/20

muestras = pd.read_csv('D:\Bibliotecas\Escritorio\combi.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(muestras)
df = df.fillna(0)
fUsado = df[df['USADO'] == 0]

cCodigo = fUsado['CODIGO']
cTenor = fUsado['TENOR']

lCodigo = []
lTenor = []

for codigo in cCodigo:
    lCodigo.append(codigo)

for tenor in cTenor:
    lTenor.append(tenor)

def potencia(c):
    """Calcula y devuelve el conjunto potencia del 
       conjunto c.
    """
    if len(c) == 0:
        return [[]]
    r = potencia(c[:-1])
    return r + [s + [c[-1]] for s in r]

potCodigo = potencia(lCodigo)
potTenor = potencia(lTenor)

for c in potCodigo:
    for t in potTenor:
        if len(t) > 0:
            if tenorEntrada - 0.5 < np.mean(t) < tenorEntrada + 0.5:
                print(c, '=', t)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Cargando los datos

Como no sé que version de python se está empleando y sólo se proporciona en texto la base de datos, se hace lo siguiente para que pueda ser verificado por otros usuarios.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# no se que version de python estás usando
try:
    from StringIO import StringIO ## Python 2
except ImportError:
    from io import StringIO ## Python 3

data = StringIO("""
FECHA CODIGO ORIGEN TENOR USADO
07/05/2020 MV0001 N 5.0 x
08/05/2020 MV0002 C 5.0 0
09/05/2020 MV0003 E 3.0 x
10/05/2020 MV0004 I 4.0 0
11/05/2020 MV0005 N 8.0 0
12/05/2020 MV0006 N 2.0 x
13/05/2020 MV0007 C 4.5 0
""")

df = pd.read_csv(data, sep=" ", engine='python')
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip() # eliminar espacios en blanco de las cabeceras
```

## Tipo de Datos

Notese que la columna `USADO` contiene `x` y `0` es decir `pandas` los trata como del tipo objeto (string en este caso)

```
print(df.info())

#<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
#RangeIndex: 7 entries, 0 to 6
#Data columns (total 5 columns):
# #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype  
#---  ------  --------------  -----  
# 0   FECHA   7 non-null      object 
# 1   CODIGO  7 non-null      object 
# 2   ORIGEN  7 non-null      object 
# 3   TENOR   7 non-null      float64
# 4   USADO   7 non-null      object 
#dtypes: float64(1), object(4)
#memory usage: 408.0+ bytes
```

Por tanto esta linea de código `fUsado = df[df['USADO'] == 0]` tendría que ser así:

```
fUsado = df[df['USADO'] == '0'] # cero en comillas porque es un string
                                # de lo contrario no funcionara la mascara
fUsado.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True) # es una buena practica
                                            # porque baja la memoria
```

## Respuesta

Hecho lo anterior, se empleará la función recursiva `def potencia(c):` proporcionada por @AndrésUribeGarcía para crear un dataframe nuevo con las columnas de interés

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "CODIGO": potencia(fUsado["CODIGO"].values),
    "TENOR":potencia(fUsado["TENOR"].values),
})
print(df)
#                               CODIGO                 TENOR
# 0                                 []                    []
# 1                           [MV0002]                 [5.0]
# 2                           [MV0004]                 [4.0]
# 3                   [MV0002, MV0004]            [5.0, 4.0]
# 4                           [MV0005]                 [8.0]
# 5                   [MV0002, MV0005]            [5.0, 8.0]
# 6                   [MV0004, MV0005]            [4.0, 8.0]
# 7           [MV0002, MV0004, MV0005]       [5.0, 4.0, 8.0]
# 8                           [MV0007]                 [4.5]
# 9                   [MV0002, MV0007]            [5.0, 4.5]
# 10                  [MV0004, MV0007]            [4.0, 4.5]
# 11          [MV0002, MV0004, MV0007]       [5.0, 4.0, 4.5]
# 12                  [MV0005, MV0007]            [8.0, 4.5]
# 13          [MV0002, MV0005, MV0007]       [5.0, 8.0, 4.5]
# 14          [MV0004, MV0005, MV0007]       [4.0, 8.0, 4.5]
# 15  [MV0002, MV0004, MV0005, MV0007]  [5.0, 4.0, 8.0, 4.5]
```

Para obtener los promedio de la columna `TENOR` voy a emplear la función anónima `meanList` que detallé en esta respuesta [Muestre las posibles combinaciones de “n” números y calcular su promedio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/245911/muestre-las-posibles-combinaciones-de-n-n%C3%BAmeros-y-calcular-su-promedio)

```
meanList = lambda l: sum(l) / (len(l) or 1)
df["TENOR"] = df["TENOR"].apply(lambda x: meanList(x))
```

Para poder agrupar los elementos iguales en la columna `CODIGO` es necesario que sean `tupas` ya que las listas no pueden ser *hashable* y aparece un error del tipo *"unhashable"*

```
# listas no puedes ser "unhashable"
df["CODIGO"] = df["CODIGO"].apply(lambda x: tuple(x))
print(df)
#                               CODIGO     TENOR
# 0                                 ()  0.000000
# 1                          (MV0002,)  5.000000
# 2                          (MV0004,)  4.000000
# 3                   (MV0002, MV0004)  4.500000
# 4                          (MV0005,)  8.000000
# 5                   (MV0002, MV0005)  6.500000
# 6                   (MV0004, MV0005)  6.000000
# 7           (MV0002, MV0004, MV0005)  5.666667
# 8                          (MV0007,)  4.500000
# 9                   (MV0002, MV0007)  4.750000
# 10                  (MV0004, MV0007)  4.250000
# 11          (MV0002, MV0004, MV0007)  4.500000
# 12                  (MV0005, MV0007)  6.250000
# 13          (MV0002, MV0005, MV0007)  5.833333
# 14          (MV0004, MV0005, MV0007)  5.500000
# 15  (MV0002, MV0004, MV0005, MV0007)  5.375000
```

Sólo resta agrupa y filtrar

```
df = df.groupby(["CODIGO"], as_index=False)["TENOR"].mean() #as_index=False para que el resultado sea un dataframe
mask = df.TENOR.apply(lambda x: 4 <= x <= 5)
df = df.loc[mask, :]
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True) # ahorra memoria
print(df)
#                      CODIGO  TENOR
# 0                 (MV0002,)   5.00
# 1          (MV0002, MV0004)   4.50 ## resultado esperado ['MV0002','MV0004'] == 4.5
# 2  (MV0002, MV0004, MV0007)   4.50
# 3          (MV0002, MV0007)   4.75
# 4                 (MV0004,)   4.00
# 5          (MV0004, MV0007)   4.25
# 6                 (MV0007,)   4.50
```

Si deseas que los elementos en la columna `CODIGO` sean `list`

```
df["CODIGO"] = df["CODIGO"].apply(lambda x: list(x))
print(df)
#                      CODIGO  TENOR
# 0                  [MV0002]   5.00
# 1          [MV0002, MV0004]   4.50 ## resultado esperado ['MV0002','MV0004'] == 4.5
# 2  [MV0002, MV0004, MV0007]   4.50
# 3          [MV0002, MV0007]   4.75
# 4                  [MV0004]   4.00
# 5          [MV0004, MV0007]   4.25
# 6                  [MV0007]   4.50
```